# How to Sort Multidimensional Array by Values of Multiple Keys, Strings and Integers

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of people (lawmakers) listing their level, state, chamber and district. What I'd like is to sort the array based on the values of these 4 keys, but with a custom order since some of these values are strings. For example, I'd want to first sort by "level" with the order of ("federal","state", then anything else), then state in alphabetical order ascending, then chamber by ("governor","upper","lower", then anything else), then district in number order ascending. Here's a shortened example of the array I'm using.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [district] => 15
        [state] => fl
        [level] => state
        [chamber] => upper

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [district] => 50
        [state] => fl
        [level] => state
        [chamber] => lower
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [district] => 0
        [state] => fl
        [level] => state
        [chamber] => governor

    )
)
```

Comment: Can you include some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @BusyBeaver - I've deleted the code since, but it was something similar to this..
`function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($a, "cmp");`

Comment: Mmh... That does not seem to help at all... I think the best solution would be to create your own object defined by `district`, `state`, etc... ; create your own compare function that works as you want it to work and finally sort the array with your favorite sorting algorithm.

Comment: Otherwise you have to sort multiple times from most important to least important key; i.e., 1. Sort whole array comparing most important key (*level*),; 2. Sort sub-arrays with same *level* by *state*; 3. Sort sub-arrays with same *level* and *state* by *chamber*; ... and so on. Ugly solution but still...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this may be outside my current knowledge (a bit of a newbie), so I may have to try outsource this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BusyBeaver's solution `cmp()`/`compare()` function is quite complex and difficult to update if you want to change order or, God forbid, add another field!

this was what I came up with:

```
<?php
function sortValue($key, $value)
{
    static $arrValueOrder = [
        'level' => ['federal', 'state'],
        'chamber' => ['governor', 'upper', 'lower']
    ];

    if (array_key_exists($key, $arrValueOrder)) {
        if (($result = array_search($value, $arrValueOrder[$key])) === false) {
            $result = count($arrValueOrder[$key]);
        }
    } else {
        $result = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    static $arrFieldOrder = ['level', 'state', 'chamber', 'district'];

    $result = 0;
    reset($arrFieldOrder);
    while ($result === 0 && list($key, $value) = each($arrFieldOrder)) {
        $aSortValue = sortValue($value, $a->$value);
        $bSortValue = sortValue($value, $b->$value);
        if ($aSortValue > $bSortValue) {
            $result = 1;
        } elseif ($aSortValue < $bSortValue) {
            $result = -1;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

// setup some test data
$arrData = [
    (object)['district' => 15, 'state' => 'fl', 'level' => 'state', 'chamber' => 'upper'],
    (object)['district' => 15, 'state' => 'tx', 'level' => 'federal', 'chamber' => 'lower'],
    (object)['district' => 50, 'state' => 'fl', 'level' => 'state', 'chamber' => 'lower'],
    (object)['district' => 15, 'state' => 'tx', 'level' => 'federal', 'chamber' => 'upper'],
    (object)['district' => 0, 'state' => 'fl', 'level' => 'state', 'chamber' => 'governor'],
    (object)['district' => 15, 'state' => 'tx', 'level' => 'federal', 'chamber' => 'governor'],
    (object)['district' => 15, 'state' => 'tx', 'level' => 'federal', 'chamber' => 'foo'],
    (object)['district' => 15, 'state' => 'fl', 'level' => 'federal', 'chamber' => 'upper']
];

// sort it
usort($arrData, 'cmp');

// dump the result
var_dump($arrData);
```

Comment: Definitely a less complex way about. Especially like you said with adding different fields in the future, which is a huge possibility. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) can solve your problem, you only have to write a good compare function that works as desired.

```
<?php

$lawmakers = ... // Your lawmakers array.
usort($lawmakers, "cmp");

// returns 0 if equal; -1 if $a < $b; 1 otherwise
function cmp($a, $b) {
    // 1. Compare level: "federal" < "state" < anything else
    if ($a["level"] === "federal" && $b["level"] !== "federal") return -1;
    else if ($a["level"] !== "federal" && $b["level"] === "federal") return 1;
    else if ($a["level"] === "state" && $b["level"] !== "state") return -1;
    else if ($a["level"] !== "state" && $b["level"] === "state") return 1;
    // 2. Compare state: alphabetical order
    if (strcmp($a["state"], $b["state"]) > 0) return 1;
    else if (strcmp($a["state"], $b["state"]) < 0) return -1;
    // 3. Compare chamber: "governor" < "upper" < "lower" < anything else
    if ($a["chamber"] === "governor" && $b["chamber"] !== "governor") return -1;
    else if ($a["chamber"] !== "governor" && $b["chamber"] === "governor") return 1;
    else if ($a["chamber"] === "upper" && $b["chamber"] !== "upper") return -1;
    else if ($a["chamber"] !== "upper" && $b["chamber"] === "upper") return 1;
    else if ($a["chamber"] === "lower" && $b["chamber"] !== "lower") return -1;
    else if ($a["chamber"] !== "lower" && $b["chamber"] === "lower") return 1;
    // 4. Compare district: ascending
    if ($a["district"] < $b["district"]) return -1;
    else if ($a["district"] > $b["district"]) return 1;
    // 5. If we came so far... $a and $b are equals
    return 0;
}
?>
```

You could also think about an Object-oriented solution (which still needs a compare function...)

```
<?php

// Testing
$a = new Lawmaker("federal", "fl", "upper", 15);
$b = new Lawmaker("state", "fl", "lower", 7);
$c = new Lawmaker("federal", "fl", "upper", 8);
$d = new Lawmaker("other", "wy", "governor", 1);
$lawmakers = Array($a, $b, $c, $d);
mysort($lawmakers);
print_r($lawmakers);



// Class Lawmaker to define Lawmaker object
class Lawmaker
{
    // Properties declaration
    public $level;
    public $state;
    public $chamber;
    public $district;

    // Lawmaker constructor
    function __construct($level, $state, $chamber, $district) {
        $this->level = $level;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->chamber = $chamber;
        $this->district = $district;
    }

    // Compare $this Lawmaker with $other Lawmaker
    // returns 0 if equal; -1 if $this < $other; 1 otherwise
    public function compare($other) {
        // 1. Compare level: "federal" < "state" < anything else
        if ($this->level === "federal" && $other->level !== "federal") return -1;
        else if ($this->level !== "federal" && $other->level === "federal") return 1;
        else if ($this->level === "state" && $other->level !== "state") return -1;
        else if ($this->level !== "state" && $other->level === "state") return 1;
        // 2. Compare state: alphabetical order
        if (strcmp($this->state, $other->state) > 0) return 1;
        else if (strcmp($this->state, $other->state) < 0) return -1;
        // 3. Compare chamber: "governor" < "upper" < "lower" < anything else
        if ($this->chamber === "governor" && $other->chamber !== "governor") return -1;
        else if ($this->chamber !== "governor" && $other->chamber === "governor") return 1;
        else if ($this->chamber === "upper" && $other->chamber !== "upper") return -1;
        else if ($this->chamber !== "upper" && $other->chamber === "upper") return 1;
        else if ($this->chamber === "lower" && $other->chamber !== "lower") return -1;
        else if ($this->chamber !== "lower" && $other->chamber === "lower") return 1;
        // 4. Compare district: ascending
        if ($this->district < $other->district) return -1;
        else if ($this->district > $other->district) return 1;
        // 5. If we came so far... $this and $other are equals
        return 0;
    }
}

function mysort(&$array) {
  // Simple selection sort. You can implement any sorting algorithm.
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $pos = $i;
    // Search for minimum
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
      if ($array[$j]->compare($array[$pos]) < 0) {
        $pos = $j;
      }
    }
    // Swap
    $temp = $array[$i];
    $array[$i] = $array[$pos];
    $array[$pos] = $temp;
  }
  // Done.
}
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Appreciate it x100000!